# NServiceBus and pooling

Tags: nservicebus

I must consume external webservice that contains three methods: start job, check job state, get job results. May I use **Schedule** feature from NServiceBus for checking if webservice has done his job or maybe I should use sagas with timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a workflow to me so I would highly consider using a Saga.

Comment: +1 The reason a saga is the better choice here is, that a saga can retain state between crashes/reboots and the scheduler does not. So if you call `start job` and your process crashes, a scheduler will not know if the job's been started or not. When using a saga, you will know not to start a job again and simply proceed calling `check job state`

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple Windows Service with Quartz.net?